# Google Analytics Data - PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to get data from analytics in my application, but I am getting this error in this class: `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`
How to solve this error?

Code:

```java
// imports... //
@Slf4j
@Service
public class AnalyticsDataV4Service implements IAnalyticsDataV4Service{

    @Override
    public boolean Test() {

        try {
            FileInputStream credentialsFile = new FileInputStream("path\to\credentials.json");
            GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(credentialsFile);

            ImmutableList<String> scopes = ImmutableList.of("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly");

            credentials = credentials.createScoped(scopes);

            try (AlphaAnalyticsDataClient alphaAnalyticsDataClient = AlphaAnalyticsDataClient.create()) {
                RunFunnelReportRequest request =
                        RunFunnelReportRequest.newBuilder()
                                .setProperty("property-<<my-property>>")
                                .addAllDateRanges(new ArrayList<DateRange>())
                                .setFunnel(Funnel.newBuilder().build())
                                .setFunnelBreakdown(FunnelBreakdown.newBuilder().build())
                                .setFunnelNextAction(FunnelNextAction.newBuilder().build())
                                .addAllSegments(new ArrayList<Segment>())
                                .setLimit(102976443)
                                .setDimensionFilter(FilterExpression.newBuilder().build())
                                .setReturnPropertyQuota(true)
                                .build();
                RunFunnelReportResponse response = alphaAnalyticsDataClient.runFunnelReport(request);

                log.info("Response: {}", response);

                return true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                log.info("Error: {}", ex.getCause());
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex){

            log.info("Error: {}", ex.getCause());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to solve the error by following the documentation on google, but it didn't work.
I saw some people with similar problems on StackOverflow, but it was with applications in other languages or very old posts

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics Reporting API v4 API does not support Google Analytics 4, and it will throw 403 for all the GA4 properties as they are not supported.

You need to use [GA4 Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) for GA4 properties.

Comment: I am already using Google Analytics Data.

Comment: Have the exact same problem, as above, have you obtained any solution? Google Analytics is utterly unusable since UA was retired. Spent over 60 dev hours on this, absolutely zero progress.